# Why is passing NSString pointer not working for me?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring

I am having troubles passing/receiving NSString pointers through function calls. I'm hoping someone can help me see what I'm doing incorrectly.

So this is from my first class...

```
void addTo(int pk, NSString* nam, NSString *descrip)
{    
    //open the database
    sqlite3 *db;
    db = [Item openDB:databasePath];

    printf("'%i', '%s', '%s'", pk, nam, descrip);
    //create new item with key, name, description, and database
    Item *Obj = [[Item alloc]initWithPrimaryKey:pk:nam:descrip:db];
                          .
                          .
                          .
}
```

And then this is the function in Item.m called as above...

```
- (id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger) pk :(NSString*) nam: (NSString*) descrip: (sqlite3*) db{

    printf("'%i', '%s', '%s'", pk, nam, descrip);
                         .
                         .
                         .
    return self;
}
```

Let's say I call addTo with inputs 1234, "Tree", "plant with leaves"

The print in the first code block outputs what I sent to addTo but the print in initWithPrimaryKey prints the following...

```
'1234', 'P?a', 'P?a'
```

Why is this? Or more.. why is it not printing what I expect?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you've written here. The above isn't valid objective-c from what I can tell.

Comment: Oh wait. Are you using arguments without names? So your selector is initWithPrimaryKey:::: I guess?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. Selector?

Comment: "Selector" is Objective-C speak for method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` is used for `char*` strings, but `%@` should be used with NSStrings.  `printf` may or may not support `%@`, I don't know.  If not, you need to use NSString's cStringUsingEncoding or UTF8String to convert to a `char*` that you can use.

`initWithPrimaryKey:pk:nam:descrip:db` is invalid (or at least very loopy) syntax, BTW, as is `initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger) pk :(NSString*) nam: (NSString*) descrip: (sqlite3*) db`.

It's important to understand the difference between an `NSString` and a `char*` string.  The NSString is a full-fledged object, with about 50 methods that it supports to do all sorts of neat/strange/(and occasionally)obscene things with string values.  The two are not in any way interchangeable.  And unlike with some C++ libraries, you can't substitute a `char*` string for an `NSString` on a call and have automatic conversion occur.

So using `"letters"` for a string will not produce something usable as an NSString -- you must use `@"letters"`.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks. I'm a bit new to Objective-c. What would be a better way to pass in the variables to the object?

Comment: you don't have to give parameters external names, but as you said, it's kinda ugly

Comment: In general, Objective-C parameter lists are repeated sequences of "keyword:(type)formalParm".  There are alternative forms, but they're discouraged in normal circumstances and not likely to be readily understood by others.  A "call" is `[objectPtr keyword1:actualParm2 keyword2:actualParm2...];`.  Note that the "method name" effectively consists of all the keywords concatenated together -- there is no separate method name for methods with parms.

Comment: @ZakyGerman -- Yep, but most people (including myself) can't remember the rules for nameless parm lists, and it's best avoided.

Comment: For the parts of a method name, I think "labels" may be a better term than "keywords". Calling them "keywords" can imply, by comparison to other languages, that they are optional or that their order can be changed.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. I already understood the NSString isn't a string bit(I was just being a bit lazy). I am a little unclear about how I should actually set up my initWithPrimaryKey selector.

Comment: Is [Obj key:pk name:nam description:descrip] the correct way to use the selector?

where key, name, and description are variables of Item. Where does the selector name go then? or am I confusing what a keyword/label is?

Comment: @DanielRHicks (should have included your tag)

Comment: Normally the invocation of an init routine would be `[[MyObject alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:pk name:nam description:descrip];` or some such.  And your prototype would be `-(id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSString*)pkParm name:(NSString*)namParm description:(NSString*)descripParm`, eg.

Answer (score 0):

When printing in the NSLog the NSString should be %@ not %s

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try using NSLog. That still doesn't explain why the printf with the %s works in the first function but not the second.

Comment: @James also when calling the first function do you type "Tree" or @"Tree"? obj-c NString literals should be written as the latter

Comment: It's coming in as "Tree". That's another thing to think about. I'm accessing the addTo function externally from a C# class so I'm a little unsure as to how to pass a C# string into a Objective-C one.